# How to delegate Spring services to a different database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have different classes that `extends CrudRepository<T, T>` of Spring Data JPA Framework. It implicit uses the global `EntityManager` bean.

Now I want to create a service that should connect to a different database. Which means I'd have to somehow inject a different em/datasource. But how can I bind a database explicit to spring beans / services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing it. What we did in one of our project is to define two different packages each for different datasource and defined different beans for them like this:

```
<beans>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.abc.repository" transaction-manager-ref="abcTransactionManager" entity-manager-factory-ref="abcEntityManagerFactory"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.def.repository" transaction-manager-ref="defTransactionManager" entity-manager-factory-ref="defEntityManagerFactory"/>

  <bean id="abcTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="abcEntityManagerFactory"/>
    <qualifier value="abcTransactionManager"></qualifier>
  </bean>

  <bean id="defTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="defEntityManagerFactory"/>
    <qualifier value="defTransactionManager"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Similarly defining corresponding entity manager factory. In this way, whatever repositories are defined in package abc will use abcEntityManager and similarly for def.

The other way I have seen it working is applying transaction with appropriate entity manager like this:

```
 @Transactional("abcTransactionManager")
```

Comment: That looks promising. Do you know how `jpa:repositories` are to be defined in annotation based spring configuration?

Comment: you can add namespace for jpa in your spring config file and then can use it: http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd

Comment: Just defined an additional tx manager bean and used your suggestion `@Transactional("txRemote")`. Very nice!

Comment: Just to add, t his is how jpa:repositories translates to annotation based config: `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = .., transactionManagerRef = .., entityManagerFactoryRef = ..)`